# Fetching metadata from keyword using Content Delivery API in SDL tridion

Tags: content-delivery

I am using the below code to fetch metadata from Keywords using Taxonomy API. I am able to retrieve the Keyword names, but not their metadata. Please suggest.

```
TaxonomyFactory taxonomyFactory = new TaxonomyFactory(); 
PublicationCriteria pubCr = new PublicationCriteria(41); 
ItemTypeCriteria isKwd = new ItemTypeCriteria(1024); 
Criteria[] arrCriteria = {pubCr,isKwd}; 
Criteria c = new AndCriteria(arrCriteria); 
Query q = new Query(c); 
foreach (string uri in q.ExecuteQuery())
{ 
Response.Write("
+ test - " + taxonomyFactory.GetTaxonomyKeyword(uri).KeywordName + "
"); 
Keyword item = taxonomyFactory.GetTaxonomyKeyword(uri);
CustomMeta customMeta = item.KeywordMeta; 
if (customMeta != null) 
{ 
IDictionary mnd = customMeta.NameValues; 
IEnumerator mne = mnd.GetEnumerator(); 
if (mne != null) 
{ 
while(mne.MoveNext()) 
{ 
DictionaryEntry de = (DictionaryEntry)mne.Current; 
NameValuePair currentMeta = (NameValuePair)de.Value; 
if (currentMeta != null) 
{ 
Response.Write(currentMeta.Value); // this is actually returning the TCM ID's and not the values
} 
} 
} 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are the keyword meta values component links? If so - you'll need to get those components separately and make sure you publish the components out somewhere. The only thing that is stored in KeywordMeta is a tcm uri in the form of tcm:0-<id>.

The same is true for linked Binaries.

Comment: They are not comp links. Actually I have a metadata schema which displays list of keywords from another Category. Doing currentMeta.Value in the above code returns the tcm id which I am able to manipulate to match the tcm id of the keyword(by replacing '0' with the pub id). Then i m using the tf.GetTaxanomyKeyword(correcturi).KeywordName to retrieve the required title of the keyword. But it's returning object reference not set error. I have published the taxonomy.

Comment: I think you're doing correct in essence. Try to debug the call for fetching the keyword set in metadata to see what's null. Otherwise, try to readd the filter or use a separate TaxonomyFactory.